# Do not create a document in firestore if string isEmpty

Tags: ios, swift, database, google-cloud-firestore

I have data which I transfer from the `firstVC` to the `secondVC`.
In `firstVC`, the user can choose two or one string and transfer selected strings on `secondVC`. And later in `secondVC`, the user can save this strings in Firestore in document.

My code processes `array of strings`, but if the user selects only one string my code must save only one string.

How can I not save a second string in Firestore if the second string is empty?

My code.

SecondVC:

```
var stringArray: [String] = []

@IBAction func confirmAndPaymentButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     let bookingData: [String: Any] = ["name": name, "surname": surname]
     let bookingRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Firestore")

     if stringArray[0].isEmpty {
         print("error in firstString")
     } else {
         bookingRef.document((confirmHallBooking?.id)!).
         collection("BookingDate").document(selectedDateTextField.text!).
         collection("BookingTime").document(stringArray[0]).setData(bookingData)
     }

     if stringArray[1].isEmpty {
         print("error in secondString")
     } else {
         bookingRef.document((confirmHallBooking?.id)!).
         collection("BookingDate").document(selectedDateTextField.text!).
         collection("BookingTime").document(stringArray[1]).setData(bookingData)
     }
}
```

Now I get an error if `stringArray[0]` or `stringArray[1]` is empty and I don't understand how I can not save empty string.

Comment: What error are you getting other than the print statement you use when the string is empty?

Comment: @rmaddy `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` and in the console I do not see print `error in secondString`

Comment: Point out the exact line of code causing that error.

Comment: @rmaddy on this line `if secondString.isEmpty {` error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: @rmaddy I slightly changed the code with which I have a problem, look please. In this line i got an error `if stringArray[1].isEmpty` error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: @rmaddy I changed the code because on the first controller I have strings which collect into an array and on the second controller I get an array of these strings and I need to break this array into regular strings and save in firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array may have 0, 1, or 2 strings and those strings may or may not be empty. So you need to check the number of strings in the array in addition to checking if the string is empty.

```
if stringArray.count > 0 {
    // There is at least 1 string in the array - check the first
    if !stringArray[0].isEmpty {
        bookingRef.document((confirmHallBooking?.id)!).
        collection("BookingDate").document(selectedDateTextField.text!).
        collection("BookingTime").document(stringArray[0]).setData(bookingData)
    }

    if stringArray.count > 1 {
        // There are at least 2 strings in the array - check the next one
        if !stringArray[1].isEmpty {
            bookingRef.document((confirmHallBooking?.id)!).
            collection("BookingDate").document(selectedDateTextField.text!).
            collection("BookingTime").document(stringArray[1]).setData(bookingData)
        }
    }
}
```

While the above works, it's ugly and it doesn't scale if you actually wish to support more strings. Better to use a loop.

```
for string in stringArray {
    if !string.isEmpty {
        bookingRef.document((confirmHallBooking?.id)!).
        collection("BookingDate").document(selectedDateTextField.text!).
        collection("BookingTime").document(string).setData(bookingData)
    }
}
```

This loop will process all non-empty strings in the array.